# How to get IIS8/Server2012/Azure to drop URLs such as *.php without generating a 404?

Tags: iis, rewrite, azure

I have been using a URL rewrite script since IIS7. This snippit from my worked/works fine on IIS7.5;

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Bad Unused Nuisance URLs -->
    <rule name="Reject Bad Unused Nuisance URLs" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*\.php$)|(.*\.cgi$)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, on IIS8 (Windows Server 2012 on Azure) it no longer works. Instead of silently dropping the request I get a 404. I don't want the request to get that far.

I figured that perhaps it was getting processed by something else earlier in the pipeline, so I tried IIS Request Filtering instead;

```
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false" allowHighBitCharacters="false">
        ...
            <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false" applyToWebDAV="true">
                <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        ...
                <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="false" />
                <add fileExtension=".cgi" allowed="false" />
            </fileExtensions>
                    ...
       </requestFiltering>
```

But that made no difference, which isn't unexpected since I have `allowUnlisted=false` anyway.

These URLs are still making it through to my app in the form of my custom 404 page. How do I get them to get simply terminated ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I can get this to pass the request on to the URL Rewrite handler (which will then drop it silently) as long as I do the following;

```
            <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="true" />
            <add fileExtension=".cgi" allowed="true" />
```

And then to allow it to attempt to run through my static file handler;

```
<staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
   ....  
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".php" mimeType="text/html" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".cgi" mimeType="text/html" />
```

But that feels very wrong indeed.

Actually, I also added this to my `<handlers/>` section rather than go through the static file processor, which would be a little safer in the case of misconfiguration, but it's still not a very pretty scenario;

```
            <add name="No-PHP" path="*.php" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
            <add name="No-CGI" path="*.cgi" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
```

Is this simply a limitation of IIS request filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be making it harder than needed. You can do this pretty easily using the URLScan extension from Microsoft to tighten security on your IIS and then blocking this and other things you want with it's rules.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan

In the configuration, you can do it globally or by the site with something similar to below. (This is a crude example)

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" >
     <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="false"/>
    </fileExtensions>
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Reference: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in my question I'm already using requestFiltering. The issue is that it generates a 404 error that then needs to be handled by my app. It doesn't silently reject which is what I need. That's why to solve it in my answer I had to do the reverse by allowing it through and then dropping it in web.config.